# Python: Issue with rapidly reading and writing excel files after web scraping? Works for a bit then weird issues come up

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I developed a script that would pull data from a live-updated site tracking coronavirus data. I set it up to pull data every 30 minutes but recently tested it on updates every 30 seconds.

The idea is that it creates the request to the site, pulls the html, creates a list of all of the data I need, then restructures into a dataframe (basically it's the country, the cases, deaths, etc.).

Then it will take each row and append to the rows of each of the 123 excel files that are for the various countries. This will work well for, I believe, somewhere in the range of 30-50 iterations before it either causes file corruptions or weird data entries.

I have my code below. I know it's poorly written (my initial reasoning was I felt confident I could set it up quickly and I wanted to collect data quickly.. unfortunately I overestimated my abilities but now I want to learn what went wrong). Below my code I'll include sample output.

PLEASE note that this 30 second interval code pull is only for quick testing. I don't usually look to send that many requests for months. I just wanted to see what the issue was. Originally it was set to pull every 30 minutes when I detected this issue.

See below for the code:

```
import schedule
import time

def RecurringProcess2():
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    import numpy as np
    from os import listdir
    import os

    try:
        extractTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        extractTime = str(extractTime)
        print("Access Initiated at " + extractTime)
        link = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser').findAll('td')#[1107].get_text()

        table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date and Time','Country','Total Cases','New Cases','Total Deaths','New Deaths','Total Recovered','Active Cases','Serious Critical','Total Cases/1M pop'])
        soupList = []

        for i in range(1107):
            value = soup[i].get_text()
            soupList.insert(i,value)

        table = np.reshape(soupList,(123,-1))
        table = pd.DataFrame(table)
        table.columns=['Country','Total Cases','New Cases (+)','Total Deaths','New Deaths (+)','Total Recovered','Active Cases','Serious Critical','Total Cases/1M pop']
        table['Date & Time'] = extractTime

        #Below code is run once to generate the initial files. That's it.
        # for i in range(122):
        #     fileName = table.iloc[i,0] + '.xlsx'
        #     table.iloc[i:i+1,:].to_excel(fileName)

        FilesDirectory = 'D:\\Professional\\Coronavirus'
        fileType = '.csv'
        filenames = listdir(FilesDirectory)
        DataFiles = [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(fileType) ]

        for file in DataFiles:
            countryData = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=0)
            MatchedCountry = table.loc[table['Country'] == str(file)[:-4]]
            if file == ' USA .csv':
                print("Country Data Rows: ",len(countryData))
                if os.stat(file).st_size < 1500:
                    print("File Size under 1500")
            countryData = countryData.append(MatchedCountry)
            countryData.to_csv(FilesDirectory+'\\'+file, index=False)

    except :
        pass

    print("Process Complete!")

    return

schedule.every(30).seconds.do(RecurringProcess2)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I check the code after some number of iterations (usually successful for like 30-50) it has either displayed only 2 rows and lost all other rows, or it'll keep appending while deleting a single entry in the row above while two rows above loses 2 entries, etc. (essentially forming a triangle of sorts).

[image: Image of what data on USA looks like]

Above that image would be a few hundred empty rows. Does anyone have an idea of what is going wrong here? I'd consider this a failed attempt but would still like to learn from this attempt. I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per my understanding the webpage only has one table element. My suggestion would be to use pandas read_html method as it provides clean and structured table. 
Try the below code you can modify to schedule the same:-

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
```

Comment: Hey Prakhar. Greatly appreciate that info, I wasn't aware that pandas had a read_html function like that. The only thing is that it still wouldn't explain the strange behavior on the final reads and writes. It usually seems to structure the initial table correctly but then messes up at some point when I separate it out.

Still, I appreciate that callout. I'll look into the function. I didn't really like that I was manually specifying an index and started worrying that they might add new countries to the table so this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm still evaluating this solution. So far it works almost perfectly for 77 rows.

Originally I had set the script up to run for .xlsx files. I converted everything to .csv but retained the index column code:

```
countryData = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=0)
```

I started realizing that things were being ordered differently every time the script ran. I have since removed that from the code and so far it works. Almost.

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1
0   7
7
```

For some reason I have the above output in every file. I don't know why. But it's in the first 2 columns yet it still seems to be reading and writing correctly. Not sure what's going on here.